# Oracle SQL Developer Menu is missing

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I cannot see my top application menu.  How can I restore it back?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyoWx.png)

Comment: see what happens when u click `F10`

Comment: nothing happens.. I still can't see the menu and toolbar

Comment: did you try pressing the `ALT` key if you are using windows?

Answer (score 0):

**The top application menu is a draggable toolbar**. Maybe you lost it somewhere in your desktop *(like I did)*.

Try finding it, then drag it upward to where it's supposed to be.